# What's Causing Segmentation Fault Error?

Tags: c

When I run my code and select option 2 or 3, after inputting my string, I get a segmentation fault error and I don't see what is causing the error. I'm assuming something is up with my encrypt and decrypt functions, but I'm not sure what.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 500
int getUserChoice()
{
    int decision = 0;

    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |\n");
    printf("| 2) Encrypt a message        |\n");
    printf("| 3) Decrypt a message        |\n");
    printf("| 4) Quit                     |\n");
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("Option: ");
    scanf("%d", &decision);
    if(decision <= 0 || decision >= 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return decision;
}
int getShift()
{
    int key = 3;
    printf("Enter new shift value: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    return key;
}
void getString(char buf[])
{
    char c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
    }
    printf("Input: ");
    fgets(buf, SIZE, stdin);
    printf("Output: %s\n", buf[i]);

} 
void encrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (strlen(buf-1));++i)
    {

        buf[i] = buf[i] + shift;

    }

}
void decrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (strlen(buf-1)); ++i)
    {

        buf[i] = buf[i] - shift;

    }

}
int main()
{
    char userStr[SIZE];
    int shift = 3;
    int number;
    while(1)
    {
         number = getUserChoice();
        if(number == 1)
        {
            shift = getShift();
        }
        if (number == 2)
        {
            getString(userStr);
            encrypt(userStr, shift);
        }
        if (number == 3)
        {
            getString(userStr);
            decrypt(userStr, shift);
        }
        if (number == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why are you subtracting `1` from `buf`? That accesses outside the buffer, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: i hope it was just a typo and you intended to do `for(i = 0; i < (strlen(buf)-1);++i)` but it should be just `for(i = 0; i < strlen(buf);++i)`

Comment: When I encrypt and decrypt my string, I don't want to also encrypt and decrypt newline or null characters.

Comment: Then remove the newline in `getString()`; you should also discard any characters that may be left in the input stream if the user input is larger than `SIZE - 1`.

Comment: Also, you should declare `int c`, not `char c`, to hold the value of `EOF`.

Comment: `printf("Output: %s\n", buf[i]);` --> `printf("Output: %s\n", buf);
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is crashing because of this line in the `getString()` function:

```
printf("Output: %s\n", buf[i]);
```

The value stored in `buf[i]` is a `char`, but you are trying to print it using the `%s` conversion specification, leading to undefined behavior. There are also problems in the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` functions, where you try to find `strlen(buf - 1)`. Remember, `buf` is converted to a pointer to `char` in the expression, so this is pointer arithmetic. And if the result of a pointer arithmetic operation points to any location that is not in the array itself, or one past the end of the array, the behavior is undefined. So you have UB here also. I suspect that you meant `strlen(buf) - 1`, which should not be necessary anyway.

You should rewrite the `getString()` function to remove the trailing newline from the input so that you no longer need to worry about it. Furthermore, if the user enters too many characters, there will be extra characters left behind in the input stream, and it would be a good idea to discard these as well:

```
void getString(char buf[])
{
    int c;
    int i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        continue;                   // discard leading characters


    fgets(buf, SIZE, stdin);
    while (buf[i] != '\n' && buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        ++i;
    }

    if (buf[i] == '\n')             // replace newline with '\0'
    {
        buf[i] = '\0';
    } else {
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            continue;               // discard extra characters
    }
}
```

Here, `c` is declared as an `int`, to hold the possible `EOF` value. There is a loop before calling `fgets()` to remove anything left in the input stream from previous calls to `scanf()`. After getting the input, there is a loop that searches the input for a `\n` character. If found, the newline is replaced with a `NUL` terminator. Otherwise, there are extra characters in the input stream and these are discarded.

The code that prints `Input:` and `Output:` has been moved to `main()`, where it should be, so that the transformed input can be displayed.

The `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` functions can easily be improved in such a way that the `\0` is not transformed:

```
void encrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        buf[i] = buf[i] + shift;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Rather than using a count to control the loop, the loop continues until the `NUL` character is encountered.

Here is the modified code in its entirety:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 500

int getUserChoice(void)
{
    int decision = 0;

    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |\n");
    printf("| 2) Encrypt a message        |\n");
    printf("| 3) Decrypt a message        |\n");
    printf("| 4) Quit                     |\n");
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    printf("Option: ");
    scanf("%d", &decision);
    if(decision <= 0 || decision >= 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return decision;
}

int getShift(void)
{
    int key = 3;
    printf("Enter new shift value: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    return key;
}

void getString(char buf[])
{
    int c;
    int i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        continue;                   // discard leading characters


    fgets(buf, SIZE, stdin);
    while (buf[i] != '\n' && buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        ++i;
    }

    if (buf[i] == '\n')             // replace newline with '\0'
    {
        buf[i] = '\0';
    } else {
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            continue;               // discard extra characters
    }
}

void encrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        buf[i] = buf[i] + shift;
        ++i;
    }
}

void decrypt(char buf[], int shift)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        buf[i] = buf[i] - shift;
        ++i;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char userStr[SIZE];
    int shift = 3;
    int number;
    while(1)
    {
         number = getUserChoice();
        if(number == 1)
        {
            shift = getShift();
        }
        if (number == 2)
        {
            printf("Input: ");
            getString(userStr);
            encrypt(userStr, shift);
            printf("Output: %s\n", userStr);
        }
        if (number == 3)
        {
            printf("Input: ");
            getString(userStr);
            decrypt(userStr, shift);
            printf("Output: %s\n", userStr);
        }
        if (number == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

And here is a sample interaction:

```
-------------------------------
| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |
| 2) Encrypt a message        |
| 3) Decrypt a message        |
| 4) Quit                     |
-------------------------------
Option: 2
Input: hello world
Output: khoor#zruog
-------------------------------
| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |
| 2) Encrypt a message        |
| 3) Decrypt a message        |
| 4) Quit                     |
-------------------------------
Option: 3
Input: khoor#zruog
Output: hello world
-------------------------------
| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |
| 2) Encrypt a message        |
| 3) Decrypt a message        |
| 4) Quit                     |
-------------------------------
Option: 4
```